# How do I share my iCloud storage with my family in iOS 11?

Tags: icloud, backup, family-sharing

I purchased a 200GB shareable (Family Sharing) iCloud storage plan but my family members can't see it on their devices. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to back out of the iCloud Backup settings screen and navigate to the Family Sharing screen. From there you can tap on **iCloud Storage** under Subscriptions and Apps. And from there you can invite your family members to share your storage.

Comment: Didn't know you could even do that. Nice one.